# Generalised "projection" of a metric space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, inner-product

Assume we have $n$ points $p_0\ldots p_{n-1}$ which form a discrete metric space $V$ with metric $d$. Can we define a function $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(p_0) = 0$, $f(p_1) = d(p_0,p_1)$ and $d(p_i,p_j) \geq |f(p_i) - f(p_j)|$ for all $i,j$?

If the $p_i$ are points in a vector space with inner product, $f$ could be just the orthogonal projection onto the ray of direction $p_j - p_i$, but for general metrics, I do not know whether such a function exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x)=d(x,p_0)/2-d(x,p_1)/2+d(p_0,p_1)/2$.

Comment: IMO, as a simple answer one should give $f(x) = d(x,p_0)$.

Comment: I was blind, but now I see...

Comment: We've all been there, J. Fabian.  I hope you did not my "joke" answer, which was the most complicated proof I saw off the top of my head.  I was hoping that someone would suggest eliminating the axiom of choice by quoting the non linear Hahn-Banach theorem instead of the Hahn-Banach theorem, but apparently no one else was in a jovial mood.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Think about $V$ being contained in a Banach space $X$ in such a way that $0=p_0$ and let $f$ be a norm one linear functional s.t. $f(p_1)= \|p_1\|$.

It is of course elementary that a pointed metric space $(M,p_0)$ embeds isometrically into the Banach space $\ell_\infty(M)$ in such a way that $p_0$ is sent to $0$.